# JavaFx - How to get button array index if value is all the same

Tags: java, javafx

I have an issue when I tried to create multiple buttons with the same value of "x". How can I fix this issue or perhaps get the value of the buttons and then delete the specific element in an array with the same index as my button without deleting other elements as it loops through the for loop?

```
Button[] delButton = new Button[sizeOfIt]; //sizeOfIt is the size of array

for (int m=0; m <sizeOfIt; m++) {
    delButton[m]  = new Button("x");
}


for(int x = 0; x < delButton.length; x++) {                          
    delButton[x].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {     

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        //  delete the element in the array with the same index as my button i clicked
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `Button` from the `Scene` or remove it from the `Array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this using the position of the button, it'll leave an empty box where the button was :

```
for(int x = 0; x < delButton.length; x++) {     
    final index = x;                     
    delButton[x].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {     
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            delButton[index] = null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am curious if this throws a `NullPointerExecption`? One would assume that if these buttons are in a `Scene` and set to null without removing them from the `Scene`, a `NullPointerExecption` should be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

@azro example keeps up with the index to get a reference to the `Buttons`. This example uses `actionEvent.getSource()` to get a reference to the `Buttons`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    int sizeOfIt = 10;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Button[] delButton = new Button[sizeOfIt]; //sizeOfIt is the size of array
        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        for (int m = 0; m < sizeOfIt; m++) {
            delButton[m] = new Button(m + "x");
            delButton[m].setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < delButton.length; i++) {
                    if (delButton[i] != null && delButton[i].equals((Button) actionEvent.getSource())) {
                        vBox.getChildren().remove(delButton[i]);
                        delButton[i] = null;
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(delButton));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(delButton);
        vBox.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```